# Unable to Resolve: FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mapfragment

The following line does not compile:

`var mapFragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map);`

> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(int)'

My axml is the following:

```
  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

I am referencing the following [documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/#GoogleMap_Properties):

Any suggestions?

Comment: in which context, are you execute the code to get the fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FragmentManager is a getter property off Activity class, if your code is not executing within the context (method) of an Activity, it needs to go off a context object.

Answer (score 2):

As per your targeted doc suggest i found this one.

```
_myMapFragment = MapFragment.NewInstance();
 FragmentTransaction tx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
 tx.Add(Resource.Id.map, _myMapFragment);
 tx.Commit();
 GoogleMap map = myMapFragment.Map;
 if (map != null) {
 // The GoogleMap object is ready to go.
 }
```

Comment: I get a compile error: FragmentTransaction tx = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction(); "An object reference is required for the non-static field"